# Replacing more than one child node when using replaceChild

Tags: javascript, removechild

I am calling an API to generate a list for cocktails. There are two lists. The first one is a drink ingredient list. The second is a drink measurement list.

What I want to do is when I click my generate random cocktail button it replaces all of the text that is generated through the API and puts it into a list, what is happening is when I press the button again it is only populating the last item on the list even though I can see all of the item when I console log.

Here is the current JavaScript:

```
function getMeasure(data) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {

        if (data.drinks[0][`strMeasure${i}`]) {
            // console.log(data.drinks[0][`strMeasure${i}`])
            var drinkMeasureDiv = document.createElement('li');
            drinkMeasureDiv.classList.add('drink-measure')
            var drinkMeasureText = document.createTextNode(data.drinks[0][`strMeasure${i}`] );
            drinkMeasureDiv.appendChild(drinkMeasureText);
            drinkMeasureEl.appendChild(drinkMeasureDiv);

            var item = document.getElementById("measure-list");
            item.replaceChild(drinkMeasureDiv, item.childNodes[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to attach a part of your HTML, as well as the `data` object in the future. That helps others understand the entire scope of your question, and increases your chances of getting helpful answers. Take a look at [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidelines when deciding what parts of your code to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `item.replaceChild(drinkMeasureDiv, item.childNodes[0])` you are replacing the same element up to 16 times (hence only the last entry is visible, because it is the only one not overwritten).
This might be what you intend:

```
function getMeasure(data) {
    const list = document.getElementById("measure-list");
    list.childNodes.forEach((n) => n.remove());
    const drink = data.drinks[0];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        if (drink[`strMeasure${i}`]) {
            const drinkMeasureDiv = document.createElement("li");
            drinkMeasureDiv.classList.add("drink-measure");
            const drinkMeasureText = document.createTextNode(drink[`strMeasure${i}`]);
            drinkMeasureDiv.appendChild(drinkMeasureText);
            list.appendChild(drinkMeasureDiv);
        }
    }
}
```

by first clearing all the childnodes of `.measure-list` and then appending them back one by one.
*`drinkMeasureEl` was not defined in your example, so I took the liberty to remove it. Based on this example you may put it back if necessary.*

Comment: I had to change one line of code to get this to work. Where you have: 

list.appendChild(drinkMeasureEl)

I changed it to:

drinkMeasureEl.appendChild(drinkMeasureDiv)

And it is now working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: My bad, that was before I decided to remove `drinkMeasureEl` but apparently not thoroughly enough. Glad to help!

Comment: After testing this I am now noticing it is holding onto one of the list items from the previous search and is carrying it over to the measurements of the next generated cocktail. Any ideas?

Comment: I think `data.drinks[0]` seems odd (the index `0` should probably not be hard coded?) but I don't know what your data looks like so I can't judge on that.

Comment: So the data structure goes like this: data.drinks[0] and then everything following that, is set up in strings. That is why I used `strMeasure${i}` so it pulls all of the ingredients that could be in the string from 1 - 15 and displays them.